# Wordpress ACF put category name in query_post

Tags: wordpress, categories, advanced-custom-fields

For my website I am using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. I've created a template where I want to select per page which post category will be displayed. Now I am trying to display the posts with the selected category (ACF field name = categorie) by inserting the ACF in the query_posts. But somehow I am not getting anything back. The code I use is:

```
<?php 

  $newscat = get_field("categorie");  
  query_posts('category_name=' . $newscat . '&showposts=5=ASC'); ?>

  <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
     <div class="blok">
       <div class="container2">
          <div id="parallelogram">
             <i class="icons fa fa-newspaper-o"></i><p class="coltekst">Team nieuws</p>
          </div>
          <a href="#"><p class="text-align-right">nieuwsoverzicht ></p></a>
       </div>
     <div class="activiteiten">
     <ul class="list-group">
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
           <li class="list-group-item"><span><a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></span></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>                   
     </ul>          
     </div>
     </div>
     <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>  
  <?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you `var_dump( $newscat )`? I'm curious if you're using the category name or the category slug.

Comment: What I get back is array(1) { [0]=> int(3) } Array ( [0] => 3 )

Answer (score 1):

From your `var_dump()` it looks like the `categorie` custom field contains the category ID, not the category slug. You should modify your query to use `cat` or `category__in` instead of `category_name`:

```
query_posts('cat=' . $newscat[0] . '&showposts=5=ASC');
```

...or...

```
query_posts('category__in=' . $newscat . '&showposts=5=ASC');
```

On a related note, you should [really consider avoiding `query_posts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but somehow its now shows all the posts and "&showposts=5" does not work. Therefore I assume that . $newscat . is currently messing up the query. Whenever I put everything in their manually it works good: query_posts('cat=3&showposts=5');.

Comment: Thanks, got it working with the following wp_query (got rid of the query_posts):

      <?php 
                    // the query
                    $newscat = get_field('categorie');    
                    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
                        'category__in' => $newscat, 
                        'cat' => -4, 
                        'posts_per_page' => 4,
                    ) );
                     ?>

The only thing I am missing now is that whenever no category has been selected on the page, the query shows all posts instead of no posts. How can I get this to work?

Comment: After `$newscat = get_field('categorie');` you could wrap the entire query in a conditional...`if ( ! empty( $newscat ) ) { $the_query = new WP_Query( ` ... etc.